# How to set the breadcrumb for view defined pages

Tags: views, uri, breadcrumbs, 7

I have created a page using views 3 like this

node/%/classroom

How can I set the breadcrumb and title for this page.

I tried to set using views menu option but restricts me to use normal menu for path with %.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Umar

Comment: Do you want to set the title of the page (which appears between the <title></title> tags?  Or do you want to set the name of the link for the menu?  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set with hook_page_alter()

```
if (request_path() == 'your/page/path') {
    $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Home'), NULL);
    $breadcrumb[] = l('Whatever', 'whatever');
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
}
```